# "Resource is out of Sync" error while generating target Platform in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, target-platform

I get the error after I generate the new target platform. I have to restart Eclipse to get rid of this. If there any better way to overcome this error.

Comment: Select the files that are out of sync, and press `F5`

Comment: Thanks. it worked after refreshing the respective project. Is there any settings in Eclipse to refresh automatically, the way we have build automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `File > Refresh` or F5 to refresh manually.

Look at `Preferences > General > Workspace` and select `Refresh using native hooks or polling` to do this automatically.

Comment: +1 Note that the target platform isn't always part of an Eclipse project. If you get this error, enable `Refresh using native hooks or polling` or `Refresh on access`. Closing the preferences dialog with OK should then do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh the respective projects after generating the target platform.